# Database methods to get a list of non duplicated instances?

Tags: django

In my models I have a class like the following:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I'd like to find the better way of getting a list of all the groups. So far
I have two solutions:

```
groups=[]
for contact in Contact.objects.all():
    if not contact.group in groups:
        groups.append(contact.group)
```

and the second one:

```
groups=set(contact.group for contact in Contact.objects.all())
```

I think that the second one is much better because it uses generators, but I'd like to know if there is some database method like `filter, exclude , etc` that could allow me to do this.

The point of doing this is to optimize when an user has a lot of contacts but just a few groups. (In that case maybe making a class `group` would be better, but I'd really like to avoid that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

```
groups = Contact.objects.values_list('group', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: Is not bad but it returns a list of dictionaries, something like [{'group':'A'},{'group':'B'},{'group':'C'}], So I'll need an extra step to get a list of the contacts. I wonder if the solution 2 that I proposed isn't better